# Graphic representation of instances in RDF (on website)

Tags: java, jsp, graph, instance, rdf

With Protege I made an ontology that has some classes and instances. Class "Knowledge" has a property "hasSubKnowledge" which domain and range are both of type "Knowledge". I have around 200 individuals of type "Knowledge".

I made a JSP and my job is to somehow graphically represent my "Knowledge" tree (RDF). Is it possible that ontology tree would appear on my site (so I generate it with one of the Java library)? It would be nice, In case of any changes in RDF the picture would update itself.

What do you suggest me to do to achieve that?
(if this is not possible what should what program/library should I use to statically export my instance tree and upload it to my site)

Thanks on any replies.

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of things you could look into. If you can translate your RDF to JSON, there are a number of nice visualisation tools out there, such as, for example, the [Javascript InfoViz toolkit](http://thejit.org/).

[Here's a blogpost](http://scimantica.com/2010/02/17/visualisation-of-ontologies-and-large-scale-graphs/) with an overview over a whole host of graph/RDF visualisation tools...